# undefined method `find_by'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in ruby on rails, so please help me :) This is my error

```
NoMethodError in Welcome#sucess   
Showing ..app/views/welcome/sucess.html.erb where line #8 raised:    
undefined method `find_by' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x41dca80>
Extracted source (around line #8):

5: <%= @user.pass%><br />
6: <% if current_user && current_user != @user %>
7:   <% if current_user.following.include?(@user) %>
8:     <%= form_for(current_user.following_relations.find_by(following_id: @user.id),
9:              html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
10:   <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
11: <% end %>
```

This is my relation controller

```
def destroy
    user = Relations.find(params[:id]).following
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    redirect_to user
  end
```

my user model

```
  def unfollow(other_user)
    following_relations.find_by(following_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end
```

please help me to fix that

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? find_by works only on rails >= 4.0

Comment: i'm using rails ver 3.2.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.following_relations.find_by_following_id(@user.id),html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
```

Model:

```
def unfollow(other_user)
    following_relations.find_by_following_id(other_user.id).destroy
  end
```

hope it works

Comment: an explanation of why this works would be great, given it's the accepted answer.

Comment: @sevenseacat Well, Rails `find_by` is looking for most specific conditions.So if you specify the attributes conditions on `find_by` it works you can also specify 8:     `<%= form_for(current_user.following_relations.find_by(:following_id => @user.id)`

Comment: thats completely not why your answer is correct. See Robin's answer below.

Comment: @sevenseacat Sorry I accepted that robin's explanation is correct for my answer

Answer (score 2):

As you are using a version of Rails (3.2.19), which dosen't support `find_by()`, you need to use the old [dynamic finders](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders).

So most probably it will work if you change:

```
def unfollow(other_user)
  following_relations.find_by(following_id: other_user.id).destroy
end
```

to

```
def unfollow(other_user)
  following_relations.find_by_following(other_user.id).destroy
end
```